# ServiceStack SSE connections while IIS application pool recycles

Tags: servicestack

When IIS application pool recycles, all the ServiceStack SSE connections will be rebuilt. If there are a lot of connections, say 2000 or even more, a lot of exceptions are thrown on the server side. 
It says the connection is closed by the remote host(the client). I am wondering why this is happening.

Here is a sample of exception in servicestack log

```
2017-05-24 15:22:12,131: ERROR 14 EventSubscription - Error publishing notification to: 

System.Web.HttpException (0x800704CD): The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x800704CD.
    at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError(Int32 result, Boolean throwOnDisconnect)
    at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ExplicitFlush()
    at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush(Boolean finalFlush, Boolean async)
    at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush()
    at System.Web.HttpWriter.WriteFromStream(Byte[] data, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
    at System.Web.HttpResponseStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
    at ServiceStack.StreamExt.Write(Stream stream, String text)
    at ServiceStack.ServerEventsFeature.<>c.<.ctor>b__76_0(IResponse res, String frame)
    at ServiceStack.EventSubscription.PublishRaw(String frame)
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is because the long-running HTTP Connection that ServiceStack uses to publish [Server Events](http://docs.servicestack.net/server-events) no longer exists so writing to the Response Stream throws that Exception.

When this happens [ServiceStack logs the error you see above](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/409945cc5ccee53ff9b726ec9afb0a7acc5a0c79/src/ServiceStack/ServerEventsFeature.cs#L466) and then automatically [unsubscribes the Event subscription](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/409945cc5ccee53ff9b726ec9afb0a7acc5a0c79/src/ServiceStack/ServerEventsFeature.cs#L480).

Comment: Just don't understand why it sends "\n" even though it has expired?

Comment: @Hong likely a result of something trying to publish notifications to subscriptions after AppHost/ServerEvents has been disposed. I've changed it to no longer publish to subscribers after it's been disposed in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/2b60599f451021c2d8cab46614e55dc6cb55ed7c), this change is available from v4.5.9 that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: On one of my server it always trying to get a lot of auth sessions from redis. even though I have restart the application pool or even restart the server. I have checked there is no connections at all.

Comment: 2017-05-26 16:27:40,437: DEBUG 5 RedisNativeClient - S: GET urn:iauthsession:6aUTjAeU5NYNiEwE0miO
2017-05-26 16:27:40,437: DEBUG 5 RedisNativeClient - R: $-1
2017-05-26 16:27:40,916: DEBUG 34 RedisNativeClient - S: GET urn:iauthsession:dgwDLjJEtVNXwuWbNCW4
2017-05-26 16:27:40,917: DEBUG 34 RedisNativeClient - R: $-1
2017-05-26 16:27:41,432: DEBUG 19 RedisNativeClient - S: GET urn:iauthsession:y6UNLlEDjdE4BCE0SX7a
2017-05-26 16:27:41,432: DEBUG 19 RedisNativeClient - R: $-1

Comment: @Hong it's expected that each new connection accesses the existed UserSession that's persisted in the Caching Provider, this is how ServiceStack knows if the User is Authenticated or not. Accessing the UserSession is not authenticating, it's accessing the existing Authenticated Session

Comment: the other server won't do that. I am totally lost. Why the redis client is getting the sessions itself?

Comment: I also checked in Redis there is no auth sessions saved at all.

Comment: @Hong because your other server is likely persisting Users Session in the MemoryCacheClient which doesn't require any I/O to access it, but all User Sessions will be lost when the AppDomain recycles.

Comment: @Hong If the connection HTTP Request contains [Session Cookies](http://docs.servicestack.net/sessions) ServiceStack will check the registered Caching Provider to see if the User is already authenticated. Restarting the AppDomain **does not** clear the User Sessions in Redis, so when the AppDomain recycles existing authenticated users will be able to make authenticated requests without needing to re-authenticate

Comment: The other server has the same web application.

Comment: @Hong Have you checked if it's sending Session Cookies?

Comment: And there is no sessions saved in this server at all. And there is no client trying to connect to it. Nothing should trigger the auth session query. I don't see anything else other than the GET urn:iauthsession: in the log. And it is very frequently.

Comment: @Hong if sessions are stored in Redis no sessions are saved on any servers. Whether or not there is a session stored in Redis has no impact on whether ServiceStack checks for the UserSession, which is how ServiceStack find out whether the User is authenticated. The INFO command can be just Redis finding out the version of Redis Server when it opens a new redis connection in the Redis Connection pool, has nothing to do with User Sessions.

Comment: HMMM, just figured out it was because one of my colleagues is sending some requests from his workstation. faint.

Comment: Hi mythz, I just figured out a problem we are experiencing. Basically ServiceStack code is flushing connections not operating whenever a subscription is registered. If we have more than 5000 users subscribe to one channel, it is getting slower and slower to subscribe when a new subscription occurs because of FlushNopToChannels.  And when IIS recycles, the server is busy to flush connections all the time and may cause IIS hang.

Comment: In my case I can split the users to different channels, or assign a separate channel to every single user. What I am concerned is your fix made for 4.0.61 is to fix some serious IIS issue [here](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/serversentevents-with-notifychannelofsubscriptions-set-to-false-leaks-requests/2552) but if there is no new subscription added to a channel, there is no trigger to flush the no op connections for that channel, right?

Comment: @Hong the flush is only sent if `NotifyChannelOfSubscriptions=false`, i've [added a MemoryServerEvents.FlushNopOnSubscription option to disable it](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/53ac24cd5da92db9f7e3387126112fc31e937ed0) if you want to disable the \n flush. You can also any custom behavior on subscription with the [OnSubscribe](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/53ac24cd5da92db9f7e3387126112fc31e937ed0/src/ServiceStack/ServerEventsFeature.cs#L995) event hook.

Comment: Hi mythz, We are setting NotifyChnnelOfSubscriptions to false because there is no need to notify other users. And I guess if would be same if we set it to true since it will notify all the subscriber to the channel when a user subscribe to the channel. What I concerned now is that if there will be any issues if we don't flush no op connections? I read that thread and it seems it is critical to remove the connections which are not responding .

Comment: @Hong so far we've only found it as an issue on local IIS, you can do your own testing to see if it impacts you.

Comment: I just encountered a SSE client unhandled exception. It seems the url for heartbeat was not set properly for some reason. This only happens at IIS recycling. Here is the exception : System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null. Parameter name: requestUriString at System.Net.WebRequest.Create<String requestUriString>  at ServiceStack.HttpUtils.SendStringToUrlAsync<String url, String method, String requestBody, String contentType, String accept, Action'1 requestFilter, Action'1 reqponseFilter> at ServiceStack.ServerEventsClient.Heartbeat<Object state> ...

Comment: @Hong If NRE was due to HeartbeatUrl it should now be [resolved in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/758fb58a2b237c0398dede6bbd22d9fa3e184b29). Please don't put code or StackTraces in comments, either close off this question and open a new one or update this question with the full stack trace.